# Tables, background colors and rounding

Tags: html, css, html-table

```html
<table style="background-color:grey; width:30px;">
  <tr style="background-color:red;">
    <td>eazeeza</td>
    <td>eazeazeaaa</td>
    <td>ezaadsqqsdqs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:red;">
    <td>eazeeza</td>
    <td>eazeazeaaa</td>
    <td>ezaadsqqsdqs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>eazeeza</td>
    <td>eazeazeaaa</td>
    <td>ezaadsqqsdqs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Borders are not done with proper border CSS, but using different background-color.

If you unzoom enough, the grey color between the red cells will eventually vanish (due to rounding (a pixel is as small as a monitor can display) handled by the web browser I suppose). I understand it is probably a feature and not a bug, but I need these fake borders being displayed no matter what.

The bug in the complete web page is the same, but happens only in IE (IE11, with document mode I8, please don't ask), and does not need unzooming, 'though it is sensitive to the texts content inside the table, which changes headers width (but that I cannot reproduce properly with a JSFiddle, I have no clue).

I am thinking that IF I can find a way to display the grey lines (JSFiddle) even when the zoom is <100% (this is not an issue for IE only but Chrome and possibly others), I might have a solution to my bug.
But is there any way to modify the browser behavior regarding rounding and background-colors superpositions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable border width

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="background-color:grey; width:30px;">
  <tr style="background-color:red; border-color:red;">
    <td>eazeeza</td>
    <td>eazeazeaaa</td>
    <td>ezaadsqqsdqs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:red;">
    <td>eazeeza</td>
    <td>eazeazeaaa</td>
    <td>ezaadsqqsdqs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>eazeeza</td>
    <td>eazeazeaaa</td>
    <td>ezaadsqqsdqs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not what I was trying to achieve at all, maybe I was not clear enough (if so please tell me so that I could clarify). I would like the result shown in my initial snippet to stay the same even when browser zoom level is low (try lowering zoom level and the first two rows will appear entirely red, which I don't want).

Comment: This is more like circumventing the issue, as the border in the code sample is obtained with an actual border (CSS border: 1px solid grey;), not background-color :)